# How to sign out a user from a different activity with Google Sign-in?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-signin

In my login activity, I am signing in the user using Google Sign-in. I would like the logout button to be in a different activity, but I'm not sure how to implement this. I have looked for solutions online, but all of them use a deprecated library.

Here is the code in my login activity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.sign_in_button) SignInButton signInButton;

    public GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
    private int RC_SIGN_IN;
    private static final String TAG = "Login Activity Error";
    private static GoogleSignInOptions gso;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);

        gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(getApplicationContext(), gso);

        findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
                startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
        updateUI(account);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(task);
        }
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);

            updateUI(account);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
            updateUI(null);
        }
    }

    private void updateUI(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
        if (account != null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.PERSON_NAME, account.getDisplayName());
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.PERSON_FAMILY_NAME, account.getGivenName());
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.PERSON_GIVEN_NAME, account.getFamilyName());
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.PERSON_EMAIL, account.getEmail());
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.PERSON_ID, account.getId());
            intent.putExtra(MainActivity.PERSON_PHOTO, account.getPhotoUrl());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Google says to use this code for signing out, but I'm not sure how to change it to work in a different activity:

```
private void signOut() {
    mGoogleSignInClient.signOut()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    // ...
                }
            });
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for a reference. This is what I've done to sign out a user from an activity(HomeActivity) other than LoginActivity. What you need to do is call the `signOut()` method either from `onCreate()` or `onStart()` method in LoginActivty and start LoginActivty from another Activty(HomeActivity in my case) when you want user to sign out.

**LoginActivity**

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    ...
       // I've used session to save  current user availibility in shared preference to
       //check if user is already logged in or not
    if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                HomeActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else {
        //This is what you need to do.
        signOut();
        revokeAccess();
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

**HomeActivity**

```
    private void logoutUser() {
    session.setLogin(false);
    // Launching the login activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(HomeActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

In the activity where you want to do the logout, you could do something like this:

```
findViewById(R.id.logout_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                GoogleSignInClient googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(getApplicationContext(), GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN);
                signOut(googleSignInClient);
                revokeAccess(googleSignInClient);
            }
        });
```

The definitions of `signOut()` and `revokeAccess()` can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect).

The important thing is that, in both the activities, you pass to `GoogleSignIn.getClient()` the application context and not the activity context.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Use below code and also clear all saved data as well

```
if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
```